# How do I pass the # symbol as part of a GET querystring in the URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, query-string

I am using javascript (using jquery) to pass a # symbol as a GET parameter via AJAX call.

The problem right now is that the # symbol is breaking up my querystring.

Any help appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to replace it with `%23` in the string. However, instead of doing this directly you should use Javascript function `encodeURIComponent` to encode characters in the URL.

Alternatively, if you are using jQuery.ajax you can automatically encode parameters by passing them in via the `data` option.

Answer (score 4):

If you are passing the data parameter to jQuery.ajax, jQuery does the encoding for you. You shouldn't be trying to build the URL yourself.

```
$.ajax({ url : "http://myserver.com/mypage.aspx",
         data : {'key1' : 'value#', 'key2' : 'value&&'}
         ...
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use encodeURIComponent().

Comment: encodeURIComponent() is superior to escape() as ecape will corrupt UTF-8 characters that are not in ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to encode the  url using escape, encodeURIComponent function, etc to pass that character. This will turn the characters into their % counter-partts. For example, # will be %23