# How can i use "/" in rest api url?

Tags: html, rest, api, uri

I have a requirement where we make an api call and it contains "/" in the rest api uri. For example, www.abc.com/books/bookid/**1232kkjf/asdis/waew**. The bold string is the book id and it contains "/". When we use it, we receive error.

If it is possible to use "/", please help me with some details. Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have path parameters that comprises of special characters like '/' you must perform URL encoding. While creating your HTTP request you must encode "1232kkjf/asdis/waew" with

If you are using Java Client then use [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

`String myEncodedPathParam = URLEncoder.encode(rawParm, "UTF-8");`

I you are using any other client like PostMan then you can use a lot of online tools that convert string to URLEncoded UTF-8 ex. https://www.url-encode-decode.com/

This way / will be replaced by %2F

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace it with '%2F' in the string.
See similar question:
[How do I pass the # symbol as part of a GET querystring in the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111751/how-do-i-pass-the-symbol-as-part-of-a-get-querystring-in-the-url)

Also see this link:
https://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php